# How is this RAR archive able to achieve such a good compression ratio?

Tags: compression, rar

I have a RAR archive containing a single AVI video file which is 42 MB in size. The RAR archive is only 500 KB. How can they achieve such a high compression ratio?

Update: The video is no longer available, but it was a screencast of relatively still pixels (almost no motion). Stop downvoting!

Comment: Identify the codec of the file for us.  Once we know the codec it can easily be explained.

Comment: it is a *.rar file as mentioned. You can download it.

Comment: I already know its a .rar file which isn't what I even asked..  What is the video codec the video uses though?

Comment: You can download the file and extract it and reach the video file and investigate it.

Comment: by the way, how did you find the codec with VLC?

Comment: Tools -> Codec Information (Ctrl + J)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLC reports the video as [Microsoft Video 1 (CRAM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Video_1) which is a very old codec (released in 1992) and probably very inefficient compared to today's standards. Also the video is very simple with not much motion, so I would expect it to compress well.

Compression is all about the data (and sometimes the algorithm). If the data is very repetitive (like 15fps images of basically a static computer screen), it makes it very easy to compress, that is how this file is compressed so well.